# C++ Stop displaying bitmap

Tags: c++, windows, bitmap

How can I stop displaying the bitmap in my Win32 Project. I have a method that I'm calling in WM_PAINT called LoadBitmap. It's code looks like this:

```
bool LoadBitmap(LPTSTR szfilename, HDC winhdc, int x, int y) {
    HBITMAP bitmap;
    bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, szfilename, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    if (bitmap == NULL) {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, _T("Bitmap failed"), NULL, MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    HDC hdc;
    hdc = ::CreateCompatibleDC(winhdc);
    if (hdc == NULL)
    {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, _T("HDC FAILED"), NULL, MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    BITMAP qbitmap;
    int ireturn = GetObject(reinterpret_cast<HGDIOBJ>(bitmap), sizeof(BITMAP), reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(&qbitmap));
    if (!ireturn) {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, _T("RETURN FAILED"), NULL, MB_OK);
        return false;
    }
    HBITMAP holdbitmap = (HBITMAP)::SelectObject(hdc, bitmap);
    if (holdbitmap == NULL) {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, _T("HOLD FAILED"), NULL, MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    BOOL qRetBlit = ::BitBlt(winhdc, x, y, qbitmap.bmWidth, qbitmap.bmHeight, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    if (!qRetBlit)
    {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, _T("BLIT FAILED"), NULL, MB_OK);
        return false;
    }
    ::SelectObject(hdc, holdbitmap);
    ::DeleteDC(hdc);
    ::DeleteObject(bitmap);
    return true;

}
```

**NOTE** x and y change continuously.
When x and y change however, the previous instance of them stays behind.

How can I stop displaying a bitmap once it has been painted in a new position?

Comment: Without knowing Win32, bitmap is not a movable "item". Once you paint it, the pixels will remain until erased. So to get rid of "trail", you have to paint over it with something else (background color in this case).

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Probably two ways: Make Windows clear the window before repaint (I don't know how), or find a function to paint filled rectangle, and use that to erase trail.

Comment: You also might want to look into double buffering. You can draw onto another bitmap and then draw that bitmap to the window. It prevents flickering like you might get when constantly erasing the trail left by a moving bitmap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is background brush then the old bitmap is erased with each paint call. If there is no background then erase it manually for example with `FillRect` Here is example with double buffering, assumes there is no background brush.

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    ...
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    RECT rc = ps.rcPaint;
    HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP membitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, rc.right, rc.bottom);
    HGDIOBJ oldbitmap = SelectObject(memdc, membitmap);

    //double-buffer ready, do custom paintings here:
    FillRect(memdc, &rc, GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE));
    LoadBitmap(filename, memdc, x, y);

    //BitBlt to hdc
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom, memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    //cleanup:
    SelectObject(hdc, oldbitmap);
    DeleteObject(membitmap);
    DeleteDC(memdc);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit ***************

It will be faster to load the bitmap file only once. For each paint request, we need only to draw the bitmap, instead of LoadImage every time + draw.

You can declare `HBITMAP` handles as static values in window's procedure. Set it up once in `WM_CREATE`, and clean it up in `WM_NCDESTROY`. Now we can use them anywhere in side window procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    static HBITMAP hbitmap_background = NULL;
    static HBITMAP hbitmap_sprite = NULL;

    switch (msg)
    {

    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        hbitmap_background = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, 
            L"background.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
        if (!hbitmap_background)
            OutputDebugStringW(L"!hbitmap_background\n");

        hbitmap_sprite = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, 
            L"sprite.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
        if (!hbitmap_sprite)
            OutputDebugStringW(L"!hbitmap_sprite\n");
    }

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        RECT rc = ps.rcPaint;

        //setup double-buffering:
        HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        HBITMAP membitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, rc.right, rc.bottom);
        HGDIOBJ oldbitmap = SelectObject(memdc, membitmap);

        //double-buffer ready, do custom paintings here:
        FillRect(memdc, &rc, GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE));
        DrawBitmap(hbitmap_background, memdc, 0, 0);
        DrawBitmap(hbitmap_sprite, memdc, 0, 0);

        //BitBlt to hdc
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom, memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        //cleanup:
        SelectObject(hdc, oldbitmap);
        DeleteObject(membitmap);
        DeleteDC(memdc);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_NCDESTROY:
    {
        //cleapup bitmap handles
        if (hbitmap_background)
            DeleteObject(hbitmap_background);

        if (hbitmap_sprite)
            DeleteObject(hbitmap_sprite);
    }

    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
}
```

We can change `DrawBitmap` so it only needs `HBITMAP` handle

```
void DrawBitmap(HBITMAP hbitmap, HDC hdc, int x, int y)
{
    if (!hbitmap)
    {
        OutputDebugStringW(L"error\n");
        return;
    }

    BITMAP bm;
    GetObject(hbitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bm);    
    HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HGDIOBJ oldbitmap = SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);
    BitBlt(hdc, x, y, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    SelectObject(memdc, oldbitmap);
    DeleteDC(memdc);
}
```

Note, in this example I assume background.bmp is very large, and sprite.bmp is very small. If it is painted the other way around then background will hide the sprite.

Comment: Works, thanks. I'm not sure how it will go once I have a background bitmap though.

Comment: +1 for doing the blit on the invalid region rather than how nearly everyone else does, namely always blasting the entire bitmap into the paint dc.

Comment: @DenverP. if there is background bitmap then remove `FillRect`, it's not necessary. Use instead `LoadBitmap(background_bitmap, memdc, 0, 0);` then call `LoadBitmap(filename, memdc, x, y);`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Thanks, I was implementing a background brush and I wondered why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I know that this is old now, but I need some assistance. I tried doing two `LoadBitmap`s and the second one is not executed on repaint. Please help.

Comment: You should post another question and show the new code you are using. The `WM_PAINT` switch, also show where you are requesting repaint.

Comment: Ok. I'll do that now.

Comment: I edited the code to show how you can load the image once, and simply draw for paint request. Try the above example exactly as I posted. Make sure the bigger "background.bmp" is painted first. Then paint the smaller "sprite.bmp" on top of background